# How to put a component inside another component's templateUrl in Angular2+?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

If I am using templateUrl in my Angular4 parent component, and I need to include

the child component inside parent's template like `<child></child>`,

how can I achieve the same?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './foo.parent.html'
})
export class ParentComponent {}
```

Child Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <h4>Child Component</h4>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {}
```

Comment: Note that your app components selectors' name should start with `app-...` (eg: `app-parent`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<child></child>` in the `foo.parent.html` file.